# React i18Next not showing translation from REST API

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next

I have a working solution with i18Next where translation are loaded from the app.
Here how it looks

```
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

import EN from './data/locales/en/translation.json';
import DA from './data/locales/da/translation.json';

const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: EN,
  },
  da: {
    translation: DA,
  }
};


i18n
  .use(initReactI18next) 
  .init({
    resources,
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    lng: 'en', // TODO: make dynamic
    keySeparator: false,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, 
    },
    parseMissingKeyHandler: () => "" //  empty string for missing keys
  });

export default i18n;
```

Now we have an external REST API to fetch the translation from. I18Next has a plugin for that `18next-http-backend`. Here is my latest code calling the external service

```
import {initReactI18next} from 'react-i18next';
import HttpApi from 'i18next-http-backend';


i18n
    .use(HttpApi)
    .use(initReactI18next) 
    .init({
        backend: {
            loadPath: `http://rest-api.com/getfile?name=samplefile&lang=en`,
            parse: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            },
        },
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        lng: 'en', // TODO: make dynamic
        debug: true,
        keySeparator: false,
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
        },
        parseMissingKeyHandler: () => "" // empty string for missing keys
    });

export default i18n;
```

And then I am wrapping my app with React Suspense to wait for the translations to be fetched.
i18Next is calling the API and fetching the JSON but the translations are not properly loading to the app and I am seeing the translation keys instead of actual content.

```
i18next::translator: missingKey en translation labels.goToSummary labels.goToSummary
```

[image]

Not sure what I am missing here.

The response from endpoint is like this

```
{
"labels_actions": "Actions",
"labels_add": "Add",
"labels_goToSummary": "Amount"
}
```

and on FE I am using it like this
`<Link>{t('labels_goToSummary')}</Link>`

Comment: The parse function needs to return something, or remove that function....
How does your returned response body look like?

Comment: @adrai the parse function is there just to log the API response. What should it return?

Comment: parse: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
                return data;
},

Comment: @adrai thanks for the help. Yes i have to return the data in parse function and that was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74774303/react-i18next-not-showing-translation-from-rest-api#comment131977431_74774303) the problem was only the missing return statement in the parse function:

```
import {initReactI18next} from 'react-i18next';
import HttpApi from 'i18next-http-backend';


i18n
    .use(HttpApi)
    .use(initReactI18next) 
    .init({
        backend: {
            loadPath: `http://rest-api.com/getfile?name=samplefile&lang=en`,
            parse: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
                return data;
            },
        },
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        lng: 'en', // TODO: make dynamic
        debug: true,
        keySeparator: false,
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
        },
        parseMissingKeyHandler: () => "" // empty string for missing keys
    });

export default i18n;
```